# Can I change Replaykit text?

Tags: replaykit

I use record screen with replaykit. How can I change text of this alert. Or can I make my own custom alert view?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEFFp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not change it due to the limitation of Apple. For a better user-friendly app what you can do is show an alert before you call RPScreenRecorder.shared.start(). So you would have warned the users with your custom localized info.